# Naming personal email address with own domain

Tags: naming

I am planning to host my own mail server at a personal website with my name as the domain name. What is the naming convention for such personal email address at a personal domain? *my_name*@*my_name*.com sounds silly and is repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest downside of using conventions for emails (contact@ webmaster@ admin@ and others) is that it's more likely you'll receive spam. I suggest thinking out of the box here and coming up with something you like hello@my_name.com

As a side note, you probably have a very unique first name if you managed to get it with a .com :)

Answer (score 0):

i use firstname@lastname.com for my personal email, this leaves room for other people (brother, sister, son, daughter, ...) to get their own emails in the domain as well.

I also use Google Apps for this which is a lot easier, probably a lot cheaper, and a lot less fuss than running my own mail server.